# Object Not Found Error on XAMPP virtual hosts

Tags: php, macos, xampp, virtualhost

I'm trying to setup virtual hosts on my localhost, below are the things that I've done:

**Enable Virtual Hosts**

```
# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

**Created Virtual Hosts**

```
# localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# Pendu Web
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.mysite
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysite”
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysite">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/mysite.local-error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

**Edit Hosts File**

```
# XAMPP VirtualHost mappings
127.0.0.1       local.mysite
```

Now, when trying to access `local.mysite` from browser url, gives back **Error 404: Object Not Found**. When checking apache error log, the error is `Warning: DocumentRoot [/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysite\xe2\x80\x9d] does not exist`. Not really sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by this `DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysite”`, the closing double ( **”** ) quotation mark, updated it to ( **"** ).